# Creating Image control dynamically, and set Image source dynamically

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, youtube

I need get YouTube videos Thumb in my application. Sometimes need to show video thumb just for one video, sometimes for three.

To display video thumb for one video I use this code

```
<Image Name="imgVideo1" Margin="0" Source="{Binding PreviewVideo1}" Visibility="Collapsed" Tap="imgVideo_Tap" />
```

and this

```
if (GetPostByID(e.Result).NumberOfVideos == 1)
   imgVideo1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

and to strat YouTube app use this

```
private void imgVideo1_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    WebBrowserTask wbTask = new WebBrowserTask();
    wbTask.Uri = new Uri("http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + ytVideoID + "?autoplay=1");
    wbTask.Show();
}
```

But I need to create dynamically number of image control, dependency of NumberOfVideos...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ur solution will something like this--->

```
total = GetPostByID(e.Result).NumberOfVideos;

    if(total > 0)
    {
       count = 1;
       While(count <= total)
       {
          Image img = new Image();
          img.Tap += (o, e) =>
          {
             WebBrowserTask wbTask = new WebBrowserTask();
             wbTask.Uri = new Uri("http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + ytVideoID + "?autoplay=1");
             wbTask.Show();
          };
          Container.Children.Add(img);
       }
    }
```